# Group duplicate rows with different column values then send to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have this csv file `favsites.csv`:

```
Emails                          Favorite Site                                                                                       
batman@email.com                something.com          
batman@email.com                hamburgers.com         
poisonivy@email.com             yonder.com             
superman@email.com              cookies.com            
catgirl@email.com               cattreats.com           
catgirl@email.com               fishcaviar.com          
catgirl@email.com               elegantfashion.com             
joker@email.com                 cards.com            
supergirl@email.com             nailart.com
```

I want to group the duplicates, then merge the columns, and then send to a csv.

So once grouped and merged it should look like this:

```
Emails                          Favorite Site                                                                                       
batman@email.com                something.com          
                                hamburgers.com         
poisonivy@email.com             yonder.com             
superman@email.com              cookies.com            
catgirl@email.com               cattreats.com           
                                fishcaviar.com          
                                elegantfashion.com             
joker@email.com                 cards.com            
supergirl@email.com             nailart.com
```

How would I send this to a csv file and have it look like this? But `something.com` and `hamburgers.com` are in one cell for batman; and `cattreats.com`, `fishcaviar.com`, and `elegantfashion.com` are in one cell for catgirl. OR, have them in the same row but different columns like this.

```
Emails                          Favorite Site                                                                                       
batman@email.com                something.com    hamburgers.com                                
poisonivy@email.com             yonder.com             
superman@email.com              cookies.com            
catgirl@email.com               cattreats.com    fishcaviar.com   elegantfashion.com             
joker@email.com                 cards.com            
supergirl@email.com             nailart.com
```

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

Dir='favsites.csv'
sendcsv='mergednames.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(Dir)
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df_sort = df.sort_values('Emails')
grouped = df_sort.groupby(['Emails', 'Favorite Site']).agg('sum')
```

When I print grouped it shows:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(batman@email.com, hamburgers.com), (batman@email.com, something.com), (catgirl@email.com, cattreats.com), (catgirl@email.com, elegantfashion.com), (catgirl@email.com, fishcaviar.com), (joker@email.com, cards.com), (poisonivy@email.com, yonder.com), (supergirl@email.com, nailart.com), (superman@email.com, cookies.com)]
```

Comment: "send this to a csv file and have it look like this?" - when converted to csv there won't be "pretty" whitespace gaps

Comment: Yes. Instead of putting them all in one cell where they'll be clumped together, is there a way to instead put each one on the same row but different cells? (as shown above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace duplicated values with empty strings:

```py
emails = ['batman@email.com', 'poisonivy@email.com','superman@email.com', 'batman@email.com']
favs =['something.com', 'hamburgers.com', 'yonder.com', 'cookies.com' ]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Emails': emails, 'Favorite Site': favs})

df_sorted = df.sort_values('Emails')
df_sorted.loc[df['Emails'].duplicated(), 'Emails'] = ''
```

Output:

| Emails | Favorite Site |
| --- | --- |
| batman@email.com | something.com |
|  | cookies.com |
| poisonivy@email.com | hamburgers.com |
| superman@email.com | yonder.com |

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use [`pandas.Series.str.ljust`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.ljust.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) with (`\t`) as a *sep* :

```
df.loc[df["Emails"].duplicated(), "Emails"] = ""

len_emails = df["Emails"].str.len().max()
len_sites = df["Favorite Site"].str.len().max()

df = df.T.reset_index().T.reset_index(drop=True)

df[0] = df[0].str.ljust(len_emails)
df[1] = df[1].str.ljust(len_sites)

df.to_csv("/tmp/out1.csv", index=False, header=False, sep="\t")
```

Output (*notepad*) :

[image]

For the second format, you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
df = (
        pd.read_csv("/tmp/input.csv", sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
            .groupby("Emails", as_index=False, sort=False).agg(",".join)
            .T.reset_index().T.reset_index(drop=True)
            .pipe(lambda d: d[[0]].join(d[1].str.split(",", expand=True), rsuffix="_"))
            .pipe(lambda d: pd.concat([d[col].str.ljust(d[col].fillna("").str.len().max().sum())
                for col in d.columns], axis=1))
    )
    
df.to_csv('tmp/out2.csv', index=False, header=False, sep="\t")
```

Output (*notepad*) :

[image]